One-time indexing with variable
I have a parameter NI_TYPE :
parameter int NI_TYPE[NUM_ROW][NUM_COL] = '{
  '{0, 1, 2},
  '{2, 1, 2},
  '{2, 1, 0}
};

Based on the NI_TYPE, I'm creating instances, but the mni_index/sni_index need to increase only after instantiation.  Can anyone help me fix the following code?
  genvar mni_index = 0;
  genvar sni_index = 0;
  for (genvar row = 0; row < NUM_ROW; row++) begin : gen_row
    for (genvar col = 0; col < NUM_COL; col++) begin : gen_col
      if (NI_TYPE[row][col] == 2) begin : gen_mni
        axi_grid_mni #(
            .req_t (mni_req_t),
            .resp_t(mni_resp_t)
        ) u_ni (
            .clk_i,
            .arst_ni,
            .req_o(mni_req_o[mni_index]),
            .resp_i(mni_resp_i[mni_index])
        );
        mni_index++;
      end else
      if (NI_TYPE[row][col] == 1) begin : gen_sni
        axi_grid_sni #(
            .req_t (sni_req_t),
            .resp_t(sni_resp_t)
        ) u_ni (
            .clk_i,
            .arst_ni,
            .req_o(sni_req_i[sni_index]),
            .resp_i(sni_resp_o[sni_index])
        );
        sni_index++;
      end else begin : gen____
      end
    end
  end

Generate doesn't work like procedural, but I need this indexing done one time only and never needs to change in runtime.

The genvar are intended to only be incremented within a generate-for-loop. As you discovered, then cannot be incremented arbitrarily.
One option is to create a second parameter array where the row/col address maps to the expected ni_index. Then your mni_index and sni_index both become NI_INDEX[row][col]
parameter int NI_TYPE[NUM_ROW][NUM_COL] = '{
  '{0, 1, 2},
  '{2, 1, 2},
  '{2, 1, 0}
};
parameter int NI_INDEX[NUM_ROW][NUM_COL] = '{
  '{0, 0, 0},
  '{1, 1, 2},
  '{3, 2, 1}
};

This works, but can be error prone. So another possibility is to use function. Then your mni_index and sni_index becomes ni_index(2, row, col) and ni_index(1, row, col) respectively.
function int ni_index(int key, row, col);
  ni_index = 0;
  for(int r=0; r<NUM_ROW; r++) begin
    for(int c=0; c<NUM_COL; c++) begin
       if ((r==row) && (c==col)) return ni_index;
       else if (NI_TYPE[r][c]==key) ni_index++;
    end
  end
endfunction

Depending on your simulator/synthesizer/etc., the ni_index() function may be optimized better by creating a local parameter before using the value.
for (genvar row = 0; row < NUM_ROW; row++) begin : gen_row
  for (genvar col = 0; col < NUM_COL; col++) begin : gen_col
    if (NI_TYPE[row][col] == 2) begin : gen_mni
      parameter int MNI_INDEX = ni_index(2, row, col); // <-- local param
      axi_grid_mni #(
          .req_t (mni_req_t),
          .resp_t(mni_resp_t)
      ) u_ni (
          .clk_i,
          .arst_ni,
          .req_o(mni_req_o[MNI_INDEX]),
          .resp_i(mni_resp_i[MNI_INDEX])
      );
    end else
    if (NI_TYPE[row][col] == 1) begin : gen_sni
      parameter int SNI_INDEX = ni_index(1, row, col);// <-- local param
      axi_grid_sni #(
          .req_t (sni_req_t),
          .resp_t(sni_resp_t)
      ) u_ni (
          .clk_i,
          .arst_ni,
          .req_o(sni_req_i[SNI_INDEX]),
          .resp_i(sni_resp_o[SNI_INDEX])
    );
    end else begin : gen____
    end
  end
end

